# Sbt run command fails with "NoSuchFileException" on Docker container

Tags: scala, docker, sbt

I have a Play application(built with Scala) that I am trying to run on Docker container.

The following are the parts of docker-compose.yml and build.sbt I am using to spin up a container to run the sbt command.

↓ docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  service-name:
    entrypoint: >
       sh -c 'cd /root/project_dir && sbt service/run'
    volumes:
      - ./project:/root/project_dir/project
      - ./service_src:/root/project_dir/service_src
      - ./build.sbt:/root/project_dir/build.sbt
      - ./.ivy2/:/root/.ivy2/
      - ./.sbt/:/root/.sbt/
```

↓ build.sbt

```
lazy val service = project
  .in(file("./service_src"))
      :
  )
```

When I start a container with this setting, for some reason I end up getting the following error

`[error] java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /root/.ivy2/cache/org.webjars.npm/wrappy/jars/wrappy-1.0.2.jar`

which actually exists in the cache.

Where should I look into to figure out what could cause this?

**Update:**

From observation, I have figured out that mounting the Windows host directory in the container seems to be causing the problem.

Instead of mounting, copying the files/directories via `docker copy` eliminates the error...

How can I achieve the same using the volumes or it this something that cannot be done?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to copy the `.sbt` and `.ivy2` dirs.
I advise to use [sbt native packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) so it would create an image for you, instead of reinventing the wheel:
Add `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.3.18")` to a file called `project/plugins.sbt`.
Then in your `build.sbt` add `.enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)` to your project:

```scala
lazy val service = project
  .in(file("./service_src"))
      :
  ).enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)
```

You can change the image settings with sbt configuration:

```scala
dockerExposedPorts := Seq(9000)
dockerBaseImage := "openjdk:8-jre"
version in Docker := "1.0.0"
```

In order to build an image on your computer, run `sbt docker:publishLocal`.
You can see the created docker image by running `sbt docker:stage`.

See [the documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html) for further help, or ask here.
See the [Alpine section](https://medium.com/jeroen-rosenberg/lightweight-docker-containers-for-scala-apps-11b99cf1a666) if you want to run your app with Alpine (lightweight Linux distribution).

Comment: this is the way to go and thumbing up for this, but the question is related to running sbt inside docker. This might happen in CI

Comment: @dvir Actually I want to test the changes to the source code in a container

Comment: @d-_-b i see. it makes more sense now. initially you wrote that you have a play application that you are trying to run on a container.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be related to access rights used within docker image.

Check that the file does exist and can be read manually with a bash/shell from within container.

```
docker-compose run service-name sh
```

Or if container is running

```
docker-compose exec service-name sh
```

This should yield `sh` command line and run

```
ls -al /root/.ivy2/cache/org.webjars.npm/wrappy/jars/wrappy-1.0.2.jar
```

Check that file exists and what rights are assigned to it.

If rights are not the problem, do your debug within shell of the container.

Comment: `ls -al /root/.ivy2/cache/org.webjars.npm/wrappy/jars/wrappy-1.0.2.jar` outputs `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4502 Jul 12  2017 /root/.ivy2/cache/org.webjars.npm/wrappy/jars/wrappy-1.0.2.jar`. The file permission looks ok. I am not sure where else to look into...